# Kohana 3.3 Database::instance('name') not working

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.3

I have an issue with Kohana 3.3 and using different database configurations. 
I have a config/database.php with 'default' config and 'other' like this:

---

```
return array
(
'default' => array
(
    'type'       => 'MySQL',
    'connection' => array(
        'hostname'   => 'localhost',
        'database'   => 'database-one',
        'username'   => 'root',
        'password'   => 'password',
        'persistent' =>  FALSE,
    ),
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'charset'      => 'utf8',
    'caching'      => FALSE,
),

'other' => array  
(
    'type'       => 'MySQL',
    'connection' => array(
        'hostname'   => 'localhost',
        'database'   => 'database-two',
        'username'   => 'root',
        'password'   => 'password',
        'persistent' =>  FALSE,
    ),
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'charset'      => 'utf8',
    'caching'      => FALSE,
));
```

But in a Controller or Model when trying to use:

```
 Database::instance('other');
```

Kohana will still use the 'default' configuration. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to change currently used connection by kohana try this:

```
Database::$default = 'other';
```

From this line your code will use 'other' connection till you will switch it again to 'default' using same way.

You can also use another DB configuration once when executing the query in simple way:

```
DB::...->execute('other');
```

Or if you store your DB instance earlier:

```
$other = Database::instance('other');
DB::...->execute($other);
```

By ... I mean your query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the connection in a variable, or the `default` connection will be used.

[Documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/config#connections-and-instances)

Comment: yes, I tried: $db = Database::instance('other');  but there is no difference. Kohana still use the default configuration.